# Android : edit items of a list view with a popup

Tags: android

In my application i have a a listview which has a textview as row.

On clicking each row, i want a poup to come where i can edit text and i should be able to extract this edited value to update in my application data as well as to reflect new value in popup

thanks a lot for your help and time

Comment: please search before asking :S why not use `setOnItemClickListener` for your listview?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for asking questions. No one will provide you direct code. First try yourself, if you get stuck, we will help you out.

Comment: I had already tried and my code where i have implemented the setOnClickListener for the textview, which is a row in my listview is below:

My problem was that, now the pop up comes which is a editabletext , i am able to edit it, but i want the popup to diappear after i edit and extract the edited value.

So i think along with i need a button for my popup window ?
on clicking which , i should get back to my listview with edited value.
I was not getting any idea for implementing this part.

I am looking for help on this part

Comment: code :
holder.text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                 
                      PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
                         mInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_cart_edit, null, false), 
                         100, 
                         100, 
                         true);
                      // The code below assumes that the root container has an id called 'main'
                      pw.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 
                }

              });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt make it work with popup but tried alert box and was implementation became very easy.

here is the code for alert box:
http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-user-input-with-an-alertdialog

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    final View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup2, null);
    final PopupWindow popup2 = new PopupWindow(popupView,
          RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
          RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    popup2.setFocusable(true);
    popup2.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```